Remove slug before REST API endpoint
I'm using a translation plugin in WordPress which adds the language code as a slug for all internal links like this: domainname.com/en
This also results in some of my plugins endpoints being unauthorized for access since it also adds the language slug before the namespace: en/plugin-name/v1
Is there a way to force the links to force remove this language slug before the namespace in endpoints? Or a way to register all links with the slug as a rest route? I have been looking into register_rest_route, but this will mean I will have to register all possible links for all plugins. I hope there is an easier approach to this.

Sounds like a question for the developers of the translation plugin you're using. Have you tried contacting them yet?

use this function in your plugins to have the good url : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_url/

@cabrerahector To no luck yet. But will keep trying, thanks!

This issue can be handled by using rest_url hook. This hook will help in dynamically removing the language slug from the REST API URL. Also allowing the REST API to function correctly without needing to register all possible links manually.
function remove_lang_slug_from_rest_url( $url ) {
    // Here we are getting the site URL and language slug (assuming language slugs are 2 characters long like 'en', 'fr', etc.)
    $site_url  = get_site_url();
    $lang_slug = substr( parse_url( $site_url, PHP_URL_PATH ), 1, 2 );

    // This is to remove the language slug from the URL.
    $url = str_replace( '/$lang_slug/', '/', $url );

    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'rest_url', 'remove_lang_slug_from_rest_url' );

